# Medion MS-7797 : doesn't boot after install

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

My PC:

```
MEDION PC MT 14
MS-7797
Core i7, 8 GB
```

I remove the Nvidia card. Use the mainboard VGA connector.

Windows crash, due to HD failure.

I place a **new WD 1TB hard disk** and install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as the only system.

When I reboot, the PC doesn't find the OS:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected
>   Boot device and press a key

Of course, I put HD as the boot device.

I go in the BIOS. In Security, I **disable the Secure Boot**.

I install again, but doesn't boot.

I don't see which options I can change to boot on HD.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I always manage partionning myself.

So I defined :

- / 22 GB
- /home   : the rest of the disk

It's easier when I upgrade or reinstall Ubuntu.

I cannot boot on the disk when I defined the partition myself, even when I disable Secure Boot ...

I enable again Secure Boot.
I reinstall, but I chose the option "Use ALL the disk" (automaticaly partitionned)

And now, it's work.

I see with GParted a special parition fat32, EFI System Partion, 512 MB.

And the / partition after, using all the space.

I reboot on USB only to reduce the / partition and create a /home.

I receive a message "Invalide signature" for the USB drive, but it works.

I go in Bios and change the Secure Boot check to "Always Execute".
And all is OK

... Really, for us, Secure Boot is not interesting.